# The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is working in ISS but not when i uploaded it on godaddy

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

My code is working fine on IIS but when I deployed the website and try to load excel file I am getting the above error:

> Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12 provider is not registered on the local machine

1. Asp.net
2. 64 bit OS and 32 bit Office 13

```
ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
```

Comment: Please help i have installed and try every thing but no joy :(

Comment: This is a Windows driver, so you'll have to ask GoDaddy to install it for you.  They'll most likely say no however.  In that case, you have to use a third-party driver such as EPPlus (free) to use instead of that driver (http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @EvilDr can i add some dll in my solution project explicitly to solve it?

Comment: No because its a Windows driver problem, not ASP.Net.  The driver is registered on your machine with IIS, but not on the server's IIS.  EPPlus will add the DLL (use Nuget to make it extra easy), but the code to read the Excel file will be different (that said, its still pretty straightforward): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/680421/Create-Read-Edit-Advance-Excel-Report-in